# APPHOST9624 error on Cordova UWP on Azure AD Login

Tags: cordova, uwp, azure-active-directory

I'm currently trying to create a UWP package for my Cordova app which uses Azure AD to authenticate the user. For this a redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydoamin.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id... is required.

Unfortunately on redirecting the user I get the following error:

> APPHOST9624: "The app can't use script to load the url url because the
>   url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch
>   another app."

I saw [this old GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cordova-docs/issues/343) already, but the Windows target version is already set to 10.0.

Comment: Can you please add the source code (or a pointer to the sample youy used) on how you are requesting the user's authentication

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue with an UWP Javascript Application that wraps a Vue JS application and uses MSAL library for Azure AD authentication. We would like to wrap it to be deployed to Windows 10 Store.

When the application tries to authenticate ( when being opened), I'm having the same error: APPHOST9624.

Researching , I have founded this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/windows-runtime/error-codes-for-windows-runtime-apps-using-javascript

APPHOST9624: Apps can't launch other apps directly. Other apps can be launched by the user when the app implements certain contracts. For more info, see App contracts and extensions.

Contracts an extensions documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh464906(v=win.10)

**Contracts**: A contract is like an agreement between one or more apps. Contracts define the requirements that apps must meet to participate in these unique interactions.

**Extensions**: An extension is like an agreement between an app and the operating system. Extensions lets app developers extend or customize standard features primarily for use in their apps and potentially for use in other apps.

So the solution to this issue it seems goes through adding some Declaration in the UWP App's manifest file, Declarations tab

[image]

I'm researching more on this topic, so I'll keep the feed updated with the solution if I found any,

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've been able to workaround this, basically, the solution is to add all the URLs involved in the authentication and in the Content URIs section of the manifest, including the Organization's URL used to enter the credentials ( remember we are using Azure AD authentication), and setting the WinRT Access to "All"

[image]

Hope this will help somebody in the future